# How do I store information about a many-to-many relationship without the concept of a join table in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

My Firebase app contains a many-to-many relationship between Groups and Users. I'd like to store information about *when* a user joined a group - how do I go about that without the concept of a join table?

I'm using this Firebase example as a reference:
https://examples-k9xbyc0bhfwtlkdgfhs.firebaseio-demo.com/

Do you recommend doing something like this?

```
app: {
  groups: {
    group1: {
      members: {
        user1: {
          joinDate: '2016-01-22T02:43:27.817Z',
          isCreator: true
        },
        user2: {
          joinDate: '2016-01-23T02:43:27.817Z',
          isCreator: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  users: {
    user1: {
      firstName: 'Adam',
      lastName: 'Soffer',
      groups: {
        group1: {
          joinDate: '2016-01-22T02:43:27.817Z',
          isCreator: true
        }
      }
    },
    user2: {
      firstName: 'Joe',
      lastName: 'Shmoe',
      groups: {
        group1: {
          joinDate: '2016-01-23T02:43:27.817Z',
          isCreator: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official [structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) guide is a great resource for helping with conceptual design like this.

> In general, it's best to use nested data sparingly and to flatten data where possible.

You can represent the same characteristics with flatter structures.

```
membership: {
  user1: {
    group1: { joined: '2016-01-23T02:43:27.817Z' },
    group2: { joined: '2016-01-23T02:43:27.817Z' }
  }
},

groups: {
  group1: {
    creator: user1
  },
  group2: {
    creator: user1
  }
},

users: {
  user1: {
    firstName: 'Adam',
    lastName: 'Soffer'
  }
}
```

We've used a membership object to manage the many-to-many relationship of users and groups, allowing us to remove a lot of the nesting in the groups and users fields.

Assuming each group only has one creator, it's also possible to move this into the group objects, giving us a guarantee that there can only be one creator and removing some denormalized data from our user objects.

Comment: Doesn't this structure make it difficult to query all the users that belong to a specific group?